# Is there a difference between "to air" and "to broadcast"?

Tags: differences, verbs

What is the difference, if any, in the use of the verbs *to air* and *to broadcast*?

Comment: Maybe: to *air* is to do it by radio or TV, while to *broadcast* is more general.  You can *broadcast* by putting your manifesto on a web page, or by printing leaflets and scattering them from an airplane...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're synonymous.

Of course, senses other than media-related do not overlap:

> These clothes need airing.
>
> The old way to sow seed was to broadcast by hand.

Also, *air* is probably more amenable to ergative usage (though 'broadcasts' is acceptable here too):

> 'Sherlock' airs on January the First.

There are some constructions even within the media sense where swapping is not 'allowable'.

> 'which was broadcast to the whole building' // 'broadcast to the
>   Empire'
>
> */?'aired to . . .' // ?'aired the news to . . .'

Comment: I meant only "to transmit by media"

Comment: @Peter "to broadcast" sounds weird for single programs (I think that's what Ed means by 'ergative')

Comment: No! _I boil the water_ (S-V-Od). _The water boiled._ (S-Vintrans): this 'switch', where we say _the water boiled_ rather than _I boiled the water_, is 'ergative'.  And for good measure, the related 'middle usage': Water boils at 100C. (stative, not punctive) I've come across the ergative 'Sherlock [eg] broadcasts next...', but consider 'Sherlock airs next month' more usual.